# How to send sms with URL_launcher package with flutter?

Tags: flutter, sms

Hello I search a simple example (Android and iOS) to send SMS with this package

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher

In the plugin page I only see how to open sms native app with phone number, but no extra message

```
sms:<phone number>, e.g. sms:5550101234 Send an SMS message to <phone 
number> using the default messaging app
```

Comment: You cannot automatically send the sms without the user interaction. On Android you can pre-populate the textfield with a body, on iOS you cannot. See my answer.

Comment: So what if one wants to actually send the sms, and not just open the default sms app of the phone?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

On Android the full `sms:` URI is supported and you can send a message with a body like that ([RFC5724](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5724.txt)):

```
 _textMe() async {
    // Android
    const uri = 'sms:+39 348 060 888?body=hello%20there';
    if (await canLaunch(uri)) {
      await launch(uri);
    } else {
      // iOS
      const uri = 'sms:0039-222-060-888?body=hello%20there';
      if (await canLaunch(uri)) {
        await launch(uri);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $uri';
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

On [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH7-SW1) the official doc says you can only use the number field of The `URI`.

Instead as **Konstantine** pointed out, if you use a non standard `URI` and instead and instead of starting the query string with `?` you use `&` it still works as well. It seems like an undocumented feature.

> The sms scheme is used to launch the Messages app. The format for URLs
> of this type is “sms:”, where  is an optional parameter
> that specifies the target phone number of the SMS message. This
> parameter can contain the digits 0 through 9 and the plus (+), hyphen
> (-), and period (.) characters. **The URL string must not include any
> message text or other information**.

PS. to check the plaform you could use the [dart.io library `Platform` class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-io/Platform-class.html):

```
 _textMe() async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      const uri = 'sms:+39 348 060 888?body=hello%20there';
      await launch(uri);
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      // iOS
      const uri = 'sms:0039-222-060-888&body=hello%20there';
      await launch(uri);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, do you know how to add a variable number ? I tried this, but it doesn't work  :  const uri = 'sms:$Phone_Number?body=hello%20there';                         
  Where "Phone_Number" is a String variable

Comment: @QuentinGuichot strange... it should work. See [this](https://gist.github.com/shadowsheep1/3a95090e94d47509f0ee25d9a06fa300) and try on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/).

Comment: This is not true. In order to add a body on iOS you only have to replace ? sign with ampersand &. So the url must be like this: sms:898908098&body=text_to_send. On Android you use a normal URL with a question mark

Comment: @Konstantine this is strange because in the official doc you read * The URL string must not include any message text or other information.*. But if it works good to know. I’ll try and I’ll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Konstantin I tested you are right, so I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: I am trying this but its not recognising body text. Like it is redirecting to sms but it is not showing body text

Comment: Any thoughts on how to make it work when the uri is launched from a web app running on android/ios phone? When I launch uri 'sms:+39 348 060 888?body=hello%20there', the sms app is launched but the phone number and body fields are empty. Tried multiple ways but could not get these fields to be prepopulated.

Answer (score 8):

you can trying this for android and IOS:

```
sendMessage() async {
    if(Platform.isAndroid){
        //FOR Android
        url ='sms:+6000000000?body=message';
        await launch(url);
    } 
    else if(Platform.isIOS){
        //FOR IOS
        url ='sms:+6000000000&body=message';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This answer is for the new people coming in here for answers.
The previous answers are right however they won't work on iOS.
The App might crash on iOS but work on Android.

so to solve that we need to implement sending SMS in the way given below

```
  String? encodeQueryParameters(Map<String, String> params) {
    return params.entries
        .map((e) => '${Uri.encodeComponent(e.key)}=${Uri.encodeComponent(e.value)}')
        .join('&');
  }
  
Uri smsUri = Uri(
      scheme: 'sms',
      path: '$phoneNumber',
      query: encodeQueryParameters(<String, String>{
        'body':
            'Hey this is message body'
      }),
    );

    try {
      if (await canLaunch(smsUri.toString())) {
        await launch(smsUri.toString());
      }
    } catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text('Some error occured'),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the updated answer for sending SMS based on the OS of the device. I have tried the previous answers but I was facing body text issues on IOS devices.

```
_launchSms() async {
    try {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        String uri = 'sms:$phoneNumber?body=${Uri.encodeComponent("Hello there")}';
        await launchUrl(Uri.parse(uri));
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
        String uri = 'sms:$phoneNumber&body=${Uri.encodeComponent("Hello there")}';
        await launchUrl(Uri.parse(uri));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text('Some error occurred. Please try again!'),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is the only way worked for me in iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Final updated answer post flutter 3 and latest url launcher package

```
smsUri = Uri(scheme: 'sms', path: phoneNumber);

try {
  print(smsUri.toString());
  if (await canLaunchUrl(
    smsUri,
  )) {
    await launchUrl(smsUri);
  }
} catch (e) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    const SnackBar(
      content: const Text('Some error occured'),
    ),
  );
}
```