# How do you add custom text to an SMS in flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm trying to send an SMS from my flutter app when a user wants to interact with another user. I already have the phone number and I know I can open the SMS window using *url_launcher* package but that package doesn't let me add my own custom message to it. **I do not want the text to be automatically sent though.**

Basically what I want is when the *url_launcher* launches the SMS window, there is already a custom message that I have provided, so that the user can add on or remove stuff if they want to and *then* send the text themselves.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [SMS package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sms) helps. You are able to send SMS directly.

**UPDATE**
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54314857/11005027) might be a solution to set the text without sending.

Comment: I've seen that package too but that will send the SMS directly. I want it to work like how url_launcher works where the SMS application opens up, just that instead of normally an empty textbox showing up, the textbox already contains a message that I have put there.

Comment: Is this what you searching for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54314857/11005027 But it seems only to work on android not on iOS. The text is set in body `body=hello%20there`

Comment: That's what I was looking for, it would have been optimal if there was a way to include a message for iOS too but I'll just make do with Android at this point, thanks!

Comment: Instead of upvoting the comment, upvote the referenced SO answer in the comment ;-]. @baadal-bhojak  for iOS i think that using SMS package is a valid way ‘cause it uses a more native way to do it. On the contrary, at the date of this comment, it’s not good for Android due to the new Play Store policy restriction for phone/sms usage. So for Android url_launcher is the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sms.

It allows opening an SMS app with prepopulated phone and text fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the url_launcher to do this, set your url like this:

```
 var url = 'sms:''?body=Sample text message';
```