# Why can not send SMS with the URL_launcher package with Flutter on some Safari browsers?

Tags: flutter, safari

recently I found a bug on the **Web app** Flutter that I can't fix. even I don't know if it is a bug on **Flutter**. however, I can't find the best way to solve them.

**My problem :**

I tried to send an SMS with the **URL_launcher package** but in Android browsers, it is done also in Safri browsers but not in the correct format.

These two photos are of two different types of **iOS** devices, one of which displays the correct format and the other showing the incorrect format.

**Bote: sending SMS on Android is working and a problem just some of the safaris that do not showing correct format**

[image: Why can not send SMS with the URL_launcher package with Flutter on some Safari browsers?]

---

**Code :**

```
void sendSmsWeb(String message) async {
  PrefManage prefManage = PrefManage();

  prefManage.getSelectedPhonePref().then((value) async {
    selectedPhone = value;
    if (selectedPhone != "") {
      String uri = 'sms:$selectedPhone?body=${Uri.encodeComponent(message)}';
      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(uri));
    } else {
      toast("no device found");
    }
  });
}
```

I tried several other methods, but I didn't get a response, for example, when sending an SMS with Android I used the character "?", and if it was iOS, I used the & character. so I couldn't still fix it.

**Note: that my app is Flatter Web.**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54314857/10608055

Comment: What are the difference between the 2 iOS devices? OS version, model ect..?

Comment: @FaBotch - iOS 15 and 14

Comment: it is possible that Apple has changed some url scheme mechanism. Did you try by any chance with a code country formatted phone number like +1 342 344 5233

Comment: @FaBotch - I don't think there is a reason, it works in one version, but there must be a way in another version. In general, do you have an opinion on what I should do?